# CSS Problems with div at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is at the bottom of my page. It's CSS is:

```
#news-bottom {
color: white;
position: fixed;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
height: 66px;
bottom: 0;
right: 390px;
left: 180px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
background-color: black;
}
```

And I have the div's content like on the image:[image]
content html:

```
<span>
    <span><b>Teste</b></span>
    <span>Teste com BBCodes</span>
    <img style="border: 1px solid #CCC; padding:2px; margin-left: -3px;" src="images/news/empty.png">
 </span>
```

How do I make for my div's content show up something like this:
[image]

I can't use line breaks or tables, because the div's position is fixed, and now I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvAFx/) should work.

What we do is apply the `background-color` to the children of the container `div`. Then we give them some `padding`, which creates the space between them. Voila!

HTML:

```
<div id="news-bottom">
  <span>
    <span><b>Teste</b></span>
    <span>Teste com BBCodes</span>
    <img style="border: 1px solid #CCC; padding:2px; margin-left: -3px;" src="images/news/empty.png">
 </span>
```

CSS:

```
 #news-bottom {
   color: white;
   position: fixed;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 66px;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 390px;
   left: 180px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 #news-bottom span span,
 #news-bottom span img {
   background-color: black;
   padding: 5px;
 }​​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want fixed position, you can make several divs and change their `left` property to what you like.  You can use `%` positioning so they look almost the same on different resolutions.

But, I'd recommend using `float` in a fixed container `<div>`, and combine with @jmeas suggestion of `margin`s.  Something like this:

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='arrow'></div>
    <div class='item'>One</div>
    <div class='item'>Two</div>
    <div class='item'>Three</div>
    <div class='arrow'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
   ...fixed...
}

.arrow {
   float:left;
   width:10%;
}

.item {
   float:left;
   margin-left:5px;
   width:20%;
}
```